# Distribute your python package with conda?

Tags: python, pip, conda

What are the steps to vendor and distribute a python package using conda instead of pip. Specifically, what needs to be in the setup.py file and what commands to use?

Comment: Not an SO question, and the packages you get with conda are curated and verified. It's not like the other where any Joe can upload their stuff. There may be some application or something, but don't expect instant results

Comment: That’s not entirely true for just local installations

Comment: https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/index.html